# Can I take two 2-240 double pole circuit breakers and wire them in series to make an 80 amp

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a hot on-demand electric hot water heater. It requires a double pole, 70 amp breaker. Can I take two double pole 240v breakers and wire them in series to make a 80 amp circuit?

Comment: Instead of making life difficult, why not just use a 70 amp double pole breaker?

Comment: Pretty clear you should stay the heck away from your electrical panel, based on the level of "not even beginning to grasp the concepts" here. Get some books out of the library on basic household woring and read them, carefully (try to get ones that are not utterly out of date, while you are at it.)

Comment: WWhat do you mean by "wire them in series"?  And what do you mean by "cigarette"?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the heater according to the labeling and instructions. Those were approved by UL or ETL when they approved the heater.  It is not safe to "freestyle" some other installation method.   NEC 110.3(B).

If this is a mail-order special from faraway lands, it is not legal to install.  NEC 110.2.

These are the first two rules in NEC, by the way.

70A breakers are readily available at better suppliers **and they're cheap**, so you may just suck at shopping for electrical. Many people get into a "big box rut" - they give loyalty to big-box stores *based on the lie* that they save big money, and forget all about hardware stores (ACE and HWI are locally-owned affiliates), lumber yards, and most importantly - electrical supply houses.

Give us your panel type and we'll even give you the part number.  Since two 30-40A breakers take >= the space that a 70A takes, the only thing I can imagine is you think you need GFCI.  GFCI is not possible in 70A breaker. UL approved it anyway, so you don't need GFCI for that.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

- When they are in series, the current will flow through one and the other. And one of them will trip at about 40A.
- If you wired them in parallel, then roughly half the current is flowing through each. But it still is NOT a 80A breaker. More current will flow through one as compared to the other and will flip first.

  And even if it worked, you would have an 80A breaker when 70A is asked for.  So the heater and possibly the wiring is not being protected.

Besides, I  would expect both to be illegal wherever you are.

Please call a competent electrician and save yourself and your house

Answer (score 2):

If what you really mean is not series but parallel - i.e., connect two 40A double breakers, each with its own cable and join the two cables at the water heater, no you can't do that. That is called *paralleling* and is not allowed by code except with special rules at much larger wire sizes.

Wiring it up with the right type of wire and breaker is definitely possible. However, I would *seriously* reconsider this. A typical tank water heater uses a 30A 240V circuit. This is more than double that. You may not even have the extra 40A available in your service to properly power this along with everything else (HVAC, clothes dryer, oven, etc.). The way to find out is a *load calculation*. If the load calculation based on your utility service, panel size, house size, fixed appliances, etc. allows for it then you can do this. Otherwise it is against code and not advisable as you could overload your service and/or your panel.

In addition, large loads such as this significantly increase your peak demand. While most residential service doesn't charge for peak demand, it is quite common on commercial/industrial service and it is a matter of time before it shows up on residential service. Some of the major electrical problems across the US in recent years have not been due to total usage (i.e., how much power can be generated in a day vs. how much is used in a day) but due to peak demand (how much is needed *right this minute*). Nuclear, hydro and coal are great at constant demand but lousy at peak demand (ignoring whether each is good or bad in various other ways). Natural gas is great at peak demand but at a definite cost in other ways.